# Firebase Authentication password log in with pseudocode?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, pseudocode

Hi could someone please tell me how to write a firebase authentication password login code with pseudocode? Thanks in advance

Comment: Firebase has great documentation showing actual code instead of pseudo-code, so I recommend starting there: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth. If you have having trouble implementing this, please edit your question to show the [minimum code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),

Comment: This is quite a broad question, and sounds a bit like you are asking for us to solve your homework. Can you give any examples of what you have previously tried?